# How to remove the name of day displayed on Material DatePicker's dialogue box in Android

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I am using DatePicker dialog to picking date. I want to remove the name of day, which is displayed on dialog box. How to remove that name?

See following attachment see below image

[image]

Code is below ...

```
    // now create instance of the material date picker
    MaterialDatePicker.Builder materialDateBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();

    materialDateBuilder.setTitleText("");

    // get the today's date from the method
    // todayInUtcMilliseconds()
    long today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();
    materialDateBuilder.setSelection(today);

    // now create the instance of the material date
    // picker
    final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = materialDateBuilder.build();



    // handle select date button which opens the
    // material design date picker
    binding.inputOpenDate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    materialDatePicker.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "MATERIAL_DATE_PICKER");
                }
            });

    // now handle the positive button click from the
    // material design date picker
    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(
            new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {

                    //formating date
                    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    String dateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(materialDatePicker.getSelection());

                    // binding.inputOpenDate.setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());
                    binding.inputOpenDate.setText(dateTime);

                }
            });
```

Comment: I've re-tagged this as `java` so more people get to see it.